# Error invoking event, the class org.ofbiz.learning.learning.LearningEvents was not found

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have a request-map in controller as follows:

```
   <request-map uri="processFirstForm">
        <event type="java" path="org.ofbiz.learning.learning.LearningEvents"
            invoke="processFirstForm" />
        <response name="success" type="view" value="OneFormScreen" />
    </request-map>
```

In controller, I defined a handler for java event as follows:

```
   <handler name="java" type="request" class="org.ofbiz.webapp.event.JavaEventHandler"/>
```

I have a screen form as follows:

```
   <form name="FirstForm" type="single" target="processFirstForm">
        <field name="firstName">
            <text />
        </field>
        <field name="lastName">
            <text />
        </field>
        <field name="submit">
            <submit />
        </field>
    </form>
```

I also have file **LearningEvents.class** in folder **/bin/org/ofbiz/learning/learning**

But i still receive a exception when i submit **FirstForm** form as follows:

> ERROR rendering error page [/error/error.jsp], but here is the error
>   text: org.ofbiz.webapp.event.EventHandlerException: Error invoking
>   event, the class org.ofbiz.learning.learning.LearningEvents was not
>   found

Can anyone help me? thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other java services or events in this component that are working fine? I trying to understand whether the problem is in this event or the whole component setup is not complete. Start from comparing your build.xml and ofbiz-component.xml with an existing one.